# How do I solve the error: ErrorCode 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway" when running Gitlab Image in Docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab

> I run the docker command:

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --publish 4443:443 --publish 7000:80 --publish 2222:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:\
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab\
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

> When I run docker inspect the results contain 
>   "Health": {
>                   "Status": "starting",
>                   "FailingStreak": 4,
>                   "Log": [
>                       {
>                           "Start": "2020-06-09T08:33:29.190118286Z",
>                           "End": "2020-06-09T08:33:32.692188421Z",
>                           "ExitCode": 22,
>                           "Output": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\ncurl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway\n"
>                       },
>
> How do I solve this error ?

Comment: can you get the images  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest in  response of the command "docker images"

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/, you have to use this call

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Comment: I ran the command you suggested.  I still get the same error. 
                        "ExitCode": 22,
                        "Output": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\ncurl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway\n"
                    },

Comment: docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                                          NAMES
71cd6c7aff8e        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   11 minutes ago      Up 5 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:22->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   gitlab
Steins-MacBook-Air:~ steinkorsveien$ docker inspect 71cd6c7aff8e 
[

Comment: Did you read the full documenation carefuly? For instance -->  Caution: Docker for Windows is not officially supported.